# how to redirect from view to controller and pass a variable to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have tried to redirect to a function inside a controller from my view in codeigniter.
I have used following code

```
redirect('front/exam_result',$id)
```

here "front" is my controler,and "exam_result" is my function inside front.
and $id is the variable to pass.
Is there any mistake in that code ?

Comment: ```redirect('front/exam_result/'.<?php echo $id ?>);``` try this

Comment: it is working ,there is no need of <?php tag there

redirect('front/exam_result/'. $id ); - this is working

Comment: thank for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily redirect to any function/method of controller like this:

> redirect(base_url().'Controller/Method');

If you need to pass variable with function/method, you can do this:

> redirect(base_url().'Controller/Method/'.$variable);

In your case, this would be solution:

> redirect(base_url().'front/exam_result/'.$id);

It is best to use base_url() included rather than direct link like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Change comma to dot.

```
redirect('front/exam_result',$id)
```

to

```
redirect('front/exam_result'.$id)
```

Comment: Kindly Accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass a variable using codeigniter querystring as follows:

when you are using redirect method :

redirect(base_url().'controller/method/'.<?php echo $variable; ?>);
```